# WiFi Disconnect also disconnects Bluetooth

Tags: wi-fi, bluetooth, bluetooth-audio

I have a new problem that has started in the last few weeks that's been getting more and more annoying. I have a Samsung Galaxy J7 with Android 7.0.

It seems now whenever there's some momentary interruption in my WiFi, the Bluetooth device disconnects. For some reason, when the Bluetooth disconnects like this, the sound continues to play on my phone while my headphones/speaker/truck is still on and working but not playing sound. Usually when the Bluetooth disconnects, whatever is playing will pause or stop.

This is especially annoying at work where it's quiet until my phone starts blasting music (or some hot sports take). This has only started a few weeks ago - I had NEVER noticed it before. I haven't made any changes to the phone recently or even installed any apps.

I have tested this by manually turning off WiFi - at which point my Bluetooth headphones stop playing and the music starts playing through the phone speaker.

How do I fix my Android or Galaxy so WiFi interuptions don't force Bluetooth to disconnect? And shouldn't it stop playing when the Bluetooth disconnects?